# Call a setter of a field inside a setter of another field

Tags: java, setter

I want to initialize a field immediately after initializing another field like in code below:

```
@Setter
class Person {
    private String fullName;
    private String shortName;

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        setShortName();
    }

    private void setShortName() {
        this.shortName = this.fullName.substring(0, 1);
    }
}
```

The approach with scrapping the `shortName` field and using getter, which returns the desired value is not acceptable. I need this field, because I transfer my object to frontend as a JSON object (I want to print the `shortName` there).

Also my class uses `@Setter` annotation from Lombok framework. So users of my class will be able to use the desired setter with one parameter. At the same time the `setShortName()` method is private (as @shmosel advised).

The question remains open: Is it a good idea to call the setter of `shortName` inside `setFullName(String fullName)`?

And what is the best approach to do this?

Comment: What's the point of making `setShortName()` public?

Comment: @shmosel I will make it private ofc. But now I'm not sure if it is a good approach to initialize shortName this way. Maybe there are some good patterns to do such things.

Comment: I think it's fine. An alternative is to scrap the extra field and do the logic in a getter: `public String getShortName() { return this.fullName.substring(0, 1); }`

Comment: @shmosel It must be a field, because I send a json object to my frontend

Comment: I don't see the connection.

Comment: @shmosel I must initialize shortName, because I send a Person object as a json. So I cannot scrap the field. I need it in my frontend. Btw the logic is pretty complicated. Person class with 2 fields is used just for example

Comment: I think the getter-solution from @shmosel is better. If I see a method starting with `setAbc()`, then I think "ok, with this method I can set the value of Abc". But this not true in this case - as a user of your class, I can't set the `shortName`. And as small hint: Don't write setters yourself, let frameworks like Lombok handle that for you. :)

Comment: @akop But it is a setter with no parameters. And I use Lombok btw. I override the `fullName` setter by defining it as framework allows. As a user of my class You will be able to use your desired setter with one parameter as expected. And my setter with no params will be private (as @@shmosel adviced), and You won't be able to use it.

Comment: Why do you have to have setShortName() at all?  Just assign a value to shortName from within setFullName().  There's no law about having setters. You should have *separate* setters if and only if the things being set are in fact truly separate - and you have indicated they are not. The short name is derived from the full name, and is not independently settable.

Comment: I think you need an argument for the `setShortName` -- otherwise, Lombok won't actually pick it up as the setter, and will still create the normal one. Depending on the serialization library you use for JSON, you may be able to remove the field, and instead define a `getShortName()` method that the serializer picks up even if the field is missing. You may need to create a private `setShortName(String name)` to fill out the pattern for that JSON library to pick it up, but just have that be an empty method (or throw UnsupportedOperationException).

Comment: @user16632363 Good advice. But as I mentioned above the logic is a bit more complicated and the class has more than 30 fields. The analog of `fullName` setter calls 3 analogs of `shortName` setter with 10 lines of code each. So it won't be a good solution to put 30 lines of code into `fullName` setter. But I will describe all the aspects in my own answer later.

Comment: If those analogs have no commonality, then you're doomed to 30 lines of code somewhere. But I suspect there's a helper method you could invent to contain whatever's the same for each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Person {
    private String fullName;
    private String shortName;

    public Person(String fullName){
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.shortName = fullName.substring(0, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not acceptable. My class has more than 30 fields, I instantiate it via empty constructor and then use setters for necessary fields.

Comment: Then perhaps utilize the same idea within the `setFullName()` setter method instead of within the constructor as shown above. Do however check to ensure that the string passed to the method actually contains something before running `substring()` on it.